# Git ignore versioned added directory

Tags: git

I accidentally added to my project a directory which already has its own version control (which I should ignore from the very beginning). I try to ignore it from project directory by adding it to .gitignore. However, every time I update that folder its modification still appears in Git status on project directory. And if I issue the `git rm --cache that_dir` then I can't update that directory as there's not .git folder in it.

How do I ignore that directory from my project in this case?

Comment: It's a bit confusing ("that directory"). Please give a minimal example with actual commands used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already commited this directory, then it is now tracked by git, so listing it in .gitignore will have no effect. You have to delete it using the command you listed, but the reason it failed is unclear, you should add more details to your question to add the error message you receive.

By the way, the correct command is `git rm --cached that_dir` (d missing in cached).